# Compare MySQL string and get the allowed values

Tags: mysql

I am facing a problem regarding a string comparison in MySQL.

I have the following table,

```
res_id  | image_min_allowed_dimension | canvas_dimension
1         400x500                       8x10
2         800x600                       11x14
```

As you can see in this table, 
image_min_allowed_dimension column has 2 sets of record. Ans also canvas_dimension has 2 sets
Now, my goal is to get these 2 sets of record with a given value for image_min_allowed_dimension. 
Say, if I give 1024x768 for image_min_allowed_dimension in the PHP script it will give me the 2 sets of record from canvas_dimension field.

The probable algo would be,

Fetch All Records as canvas_dimension 
IF image_min_allowed_dimension is Less than or equal to a given value(i.e, 1024x768)
ELSE IF the given value is greater than image_min_allowed_dimension then return nothing.

But as the fields are varchar, how can I achieve that.? 
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Refactor your schema to store your resolutions in a sane manner.

```
res_id | image_min_allowed_width | image_min_allowed_height | canvas_width | canvas_height
```

Your future self will thank you for the extra effort.

Comment: There is a lot to be said for organizing your scheme around the queries you wish to make.  Otherwise, you'll go insane playing around with SUBSTRING_INDEX etc.

Comment: Thanks Michael,
The way you proposed is fine. It's the basic convention. But with the schema that I have any way to achieve this result that I wrote about ?